# If i have two PIR Sensors then how to registred the GPIOvaluecChangedEvents?

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, iot, motion

I am developing IoT based applications using Raspberry PI 3. I have few doubts while developing simple IoT based prototype application:

1. I used single PIR sensor for detecting the motion of the object, for that I wrote the GPIOValueChagendEvent, but this event will only triggered whenever the PIR motion sensor value changed.
2. But if I have two PIR sensors is it possible to write the one more GPIOValueChangedEvent. If yes, can you elaborate how to write the sample code using C#
3. Suppose if two PIR sensors will detected the motion of the object at the same time then what happens.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I used single PIR sensor for detecting the motion of the object, for that I wrote the GPIOValueChagendEvent, but this event will only
>      triggered whenever the PIR motion sensor value changed.

The [ValueChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.gpio.gpiopin#Events) event of the general-purpose I/O(GPIO) occurs when the value of pin changes, either because of an external stimulus when the pin is configured as an input, or when a value is written to the pin when the pin in configured as an output.

> 2. But if I have two PIR sensors is it possible to write the one more GPIOValueChangedEvent. If yes, can you elaborate how to write the
>      sample code using C#

Yes, it is possible to do that. Please refer to following code with using [PirSensor Class](https://github.com/ms-iot/pir-sensor).

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        var pirS1 = new PirSensor(17, PirSensor.SensorType.ActiveHigh);
        pirS1.motionDetected += new EventHandler<Windows.Devices.Gpio.GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs>(OnPirSensor1MotionDetected);

        var pirS2 = new PirSensor(27, PirSensor.SensorType.ActiveHigh);
        pirS2.motionDetected += new EventHandler<Windows.Devices.Gpio.GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs>(OnPirSensor2MotionDetected);
    }

    private async void OnPirSensor1MotionDetected(object sender, Windows.Devices.Gpio.GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs earg)
    {
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () =>
            {
                // Your UI update code goes here!
                pirSensorVal1.Text = earg.Edge.ToString();
            });
    }

    private async void OnPirSensor2MotionDetected(object sender, Windows.Devices.Gpio.GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs earg)
    {
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () =>
            {
                // Your UI update code goes here!
                pirSensorVal2.Text = earg.Edge.ToString();
            });            
    }
```

> 3. Suppose if two PIR sensors will detected the motion of the object at the same time then what happens.

If the two PIR sensors detect the motion, the event of *motionDetected* will be invoked for each other.